# empty и !empty не срабатывает

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой код:

```
<?php
$one = '1';
$two = '';
if (!empty($one) && empty($two)) {
echo "Переменная one полная и two пустая";
}
else {
echo "Переменная one пустая и/или two не пустая";   
}
?>
```

echo на сервере выводит "Переменная one полная и two пустая"
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А чего не так?)

Comment: Не вижу никаких проблем, все работает так как задумано, вы пробовали читать [документацию по empty](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php)? Там четко написано, что пустая строка явлется `false` и для `false` функция `empty` возвращает `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Все прекрасно срабатывает. Другое дело что empty тут не нужна и только мешает. Проверять только что созданные переменные на существование нет смысла, и поэтому условие должно выглядеть, как

```
if ($one && !$two) {
    echo "Переменная one полная и two пустая";
}
```

Для того, чтобы узнать, пуста ли переменная, надо писать `!$two`.
А `!empty()` надо использовать чтобы узнать, что переменная существует и не пустая.